# Toggle Menus using buttons in JS - But it shows both menus

Tags: javascript

i want to toggle two menus offered by two buttons.the issue is when i click on button one, it shows the menu bound with button one but when i click the other, it shows both instead of hiding the first one and vice versa, on my login page. The menus are identified by the ids of; 'reqpwd' and 'signup' in html / JS. What is worng? also suggest improvement in code if possible. My JS code:

```
    <script>
  window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('reqpwd').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('signup').style.display = 'none';
 };
function chk(elm) {
var signup_ = signup.id;
var reqpwd_ = reqpwd.id;
elm_ = elm.id;
if (elm_ == reqpwd_){
 hide(signup_);
 show(reqpwd_);
}
if (elm_== signup_){
 hide(reqpwd_);
show(signup_);
}
};

function show(abc) {
var menuBox  = document.getElementById(abc);
  if(menuBox.style.display == "none") { // if is menuBox displayed, hide it
    menuBox.style.display = "block";
} };

    function hide(abc){ // if is menuBox hidden, display it
var menuBox  = document.getElementById(abc);
if(menuBox.style.display == "block"){
    menuBox.style.display == "none";
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: How do you call `chk()`? *"also suggest improvement in code if possible"* - Run it through [JSPretty](http://jspretty.com) or otherwise fix the indenting: help us to help you by presenting code that is readable.

Comment: Please add your html,css,js code injsfiddle/snippet. It will helpful to resolve quickly.

Comment: chk() is called using html buttons. each button passes the id as parameter. e.g. the signup menu button calls it as: "chk(signup)" and same goes for the password reset menu;   chk(reqpwd) . Sorry i am new so unable to edit the question to repost hte indented code.

Comment: my html:
    <input type="button" onclick="chk(signup)" value="Signup">
    <input type="button" onclick="chk(reqpwd)" value="Reset Password">

Comment: RSKMR - Respected sir there is no css behind the scene.

Comment: 7 states of the above scenario comes in my mind.
1.    0-0   both unpressed  >   result  both menues hidden
2.    0-1   signup pressed >   signup menu shown, reset menu hidden
3.    1-0   reset pressed >   reset menu shown, signup menu hidden
4.    1-1   signup pressed again whilst menu was shown> sign up menu hides 
5.  1-2  signup pressed when reset menu was shown.>signup displayed
6.  2-1  reset button pressed whilst reset menu was open.>reset disappears
7.  2-2  reset pressed whilst signup was shown.> reset menu opens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have landed into something like this using the flag variable as a state indicator.. now the only requirement is to check toggle as well as disappear the relevant menu by the same button..i.e. if signup menu is already open, the signup or reset button should close it and vice versa.

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('regd').style.visibility = 'hidden'; //regisration msg
document.getElementById('rset').style.visibility = 'hidden'; //reset msg
document.getElementById('reqpwd').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('signup').style.display = 'none';
};
var flag = 0;

function chk(elm) {
var signup_ = signup.id;
var reqpwd_ = reqpwd.id;
elm_ = elm.id;

if (elm_ == reqpwd_ && flag === 0 || elm_ == reqpwd_ && flag == 2) {
    flag = 1;
    hide(signup_);
    show(reqpwd_);

}
if (elm_ == signup_ && flag === 0 || elm_ == signup_ && flag == 1) {
    flag = 2;
    show(signup_);
    hide(reqpwd_);

}
if (elm_ == reqpwd_ && flag == 1 || elm_ == signup_ && flag == 2) {
    hide(elm_);
    flag = 0;
}

};

function show(abc) {
var menuBox = document.getElementById(abc);
if (menuBox.style.display === "none") { // if is menuBox hidden, display it
    menuBox.style.display = "block";
}
};

function hide(abc) { // if is menuBox 
var menuBox = document.getElementById(abc);
if (menuBox.style.display === "block") { //if displayed, hide it
    menuBox.style.display = "none";
}
};
```

Comment: only one issue. even after declaring a flag to enable a button to close its own menu, it doesnt update the flag variable hence unable to close menus w.r.t their respective buttons. though switching over menus is working fine.

Comment: EUREKA!!!
VOILAA!!!
Finally i made it!!! 
adding else before last two IFs made it possible to fulfill allll the 7 conditions! so it means using multiple IFs is NOT advised as it differs than using ELSE IF!
thank you guys for the support and thanks to my relentless effrots and banging head with the code time and again for two days. *_*

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `menuBox.style.display == "none";` try using `menuBox.style.visibility== "hidden";`

**Edit:**
I have changed a few things in your code. Didn't make a whole lot of sense to me the way you're setting the styles on load (missing HTML), so I had to use IDs that made sense to me.

**Edit:**
Ok, my bad. I updated the code. I think the problem is on `hide` you're using double equals instead of single equals on `menuBox.style.display == "none";`. Thus the menu is never hiding.

https://codepen.io/juanferrer/pen/qmOmWa

Comment: Why would that help?

Comment: didnt help. secondly, the menus should have been invisible in case i repress the same button.. alot of fuzz in it.

Comment: nice try sir Juan Ferrer. But only one issue. as i highlighted in my comments above. 
the buttons don't make their own bound menus to disappear when pressed.e.g. the signup button wont make the shown up signup menu to disappear..so goes for the reset menu.  secondly the initial state should be set to none.means both invisible initially!